# How do I feed a string from 1 function into 2 other functions, and print it in python?

Tags: python

I'm creating a text adventure game, and want to make it so if the user types '`x`' or '`examine`', it prints the description for a room (which is stored in a string inside the a function)

This is the code:

```
def look(dsc):
    print(dsc)


def usr_input(dsc):


    a = input(">>> ")
    if a == "examine" or a == "x":
        look(dsc)
    if a == "help":
        print("north, n, east, e, south, s, west, w, up, u, down, d, inventory, i, examine, x")
    if a == "north" or a == "n" or a == "forwards":
        return "north"
    if a == "east" or a == "e" or a == "right":
        return "east"
    if a == "south" or a == "s" or a == "backwards":
        return "south"
    if a == "west" or a == "w" or a == "left":
        return "west"
    if a == "up" or a == "u":
        return "up"
    if a == "down" or a == "d":
        return "down"
    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand that. (Type 'help' for a list of commands")
        usr_input()
        return False


def room_00():
    room_description = "Description goes here"
    print(room_description)
    usr_input(room_description)


room_00()
```

Basically, I need the function '`look`' to print the description for that room whenever the user types `x`, but I can't get the functions to link.

Comment: Fix your code indentation

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paste it properly. But it is indented in the editor.

Comment: Please, fix the indentation in the code as well

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Thanks Dadep for the edit, and that other guy who posted the answer and deleted it. I changed it so variable 'bla' is returned by the look function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to run without any issue, ignore the guy above, Python 3 does need brackets for print calls.

It is returning a traceback though because on line 28, you're calling the usr_input() function without providing a parameter.

You can fix this by defining the function like so:

```
def look(dsc=''):
    print(dsc)
```

This will pass an empty string to the function unless you pass it a string of your own.

The other issue is that you're using raw if statements. So that last evaluation here:

```
if a == "down" or a == "d":
    return "down"
else:
    print("Sorry, I don't understand that. (Type 'help' for a list of commands")
    usr_input()
    return False
```

goes to the else branch because x is neither "down" nor "a", you should replace all if statements below the first one with elif, and leave the last else in place

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work much easier than what I had previously.

Answer (score 0):

Try `a = raw_input('>>> ')` and then `a = a.strip()`

also

```
def look(dsc):
   print dsc
```

You need a tab there and no need for ()

Answer (score 0):

I think the right solution will be creating the class Room, instances of which would store room description and maybe something else, perhaps, a list of doors to other rooms (you are not going to have only one room, are you?)

And this class should also have `look` method doing you already know what.

I think you should store the current room in some global variable and when you need the current room's description, you just access that variable, get the Room object and call its `look` method.

As I know, accessing function local variable is impossible. If I am wrong, correct me please.